# Can I click a button in a webbrowser using only the value of it?

Tags: c#, browser

I have a webbrowser. In the browser's page there is a button. Its value is

```
Create my account
```

I want to click this button using only its name. It doesn't have an name so I can't use getElementByID. I tried:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Create my account").InvokeMember("Click");
```

but that just errored out.

There is **no** ID for this button

Answer (score 0):

Use the page's [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/) to obtain a reference to the element in question. Use development tools found in most browsers to locate where in the DOM tree the button is.

Comment: Oh I just realized this is tagged C#, so I'm not sure this is still relevant XD

Answer (score 0):

You need the attribute Equals Selector. [This should be helpful](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: I don't get it, that doesn't look like C#

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome in options-tools-programers tools will open in the bottom of browser
then in lower left corner you will see a magnifying glass icon,click it,then you just have to click the desired element that it shows the information.
I worked on something like that and button has id="something"
hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with like this:(see this example)

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("To your register account url");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
        {
            if (btn.InnerText == "Create my account")
            {
                btn.InvokeMember("Click");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```